# Regex that will capture group with exceptions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a group that contains the word, but only in the condition that the word is prefixed with a hyphen and another word.

Take this example for instance:

**Passing Examples**

```
docs-world
docs-foo
docs-hello
hello-world
hello
```

**Failing Examples**

```
docs
```

The word in question is "docs". If the word is appended by a hyphen, I want to correctly match it into a group.

*Bonus points*: if you can do the same for "refs".

Here is an [example](https://regexr.com/48b3q)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understand the question, but could this work?

```
([a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+)
```

It matches one or more letters, then a hyphen, then one or more letters again.

```
foo  (not matched)
-foo  (not matched)
foo-bar  (matched)
```

Try it live here: https://regex101.com/r/qIknsi/1

Edit, if it needs to match *only* docs or refs, then a hyphen, then a word, then this should work:

```
((?:docs|refs)-[a-zA-Z]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a positive lookahead.

```js
console.log(
    ['docs-world', 'docs-foo', 'docs-hello', 'docs']
        .map(RegExp.prototype.test, /docs(?=-)/)
);
```